# How to I put ads on 100% JavaScript web applications?

Tags: javascript, ads

Placing ads on JavaScript web applications has turned out to be much harder than I thought. First of all, when I say "100% JavaScript web application" I mean a tiny HTML file that loads and initiates a JavaScript file which draws all the content on the page. In other words, the website is completely empty until the JavaScript has executed.

Adsense is out of the question. They immediately deny your ad application based on an automatic scan of the website where they "discover" that the page "has no content". I've sent a bunch of mails to Adsense support trying to get somebody to manually check the application instead, but they have all been responded to by the same auto-generated "no content" email.

I have also tried using Chitika, but after hours of trying to get the ad to display I've given up. It simply doesn't work when I add the ad code ***after*** the page has opened, which I have to do in a JavaScript application. I also tried placing the ad code in an iframe, which does work, but the ad loses the context of the page, which is quite important because it can't find the Google search terms.

Do you have any experience with placing ads on JavaScript applications? How do you do it?

Comment: What about adding some hidden content just to make AdSense happy?

Comment: @JanDvorak: Is Google OK with that? I would hate to have my account banned for circumventing the rules.

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you can ask them.

Comment: What type of application is this? Does the entire DOM need rendering via JS? Are you ok that non JS-enabled user agents (as per this Google bot) will not see any of your app?

Comment: @DanJ: I don't understand what you mean by "Are you ok that...", but yes I'm aware that they won't see my app, and that's the problem with Adsense as I explain in my question.

Answer (score 3):

@Dan in the comments has a point here -- if Adsense can't get any sense out of your site, then neither will the Google bot, which means your site won't show up in Google.

If you want any kind of traffic for your site, then the very least you need to do is create a splash screen from regular HTML that Google can hook into. If that is then overwritten by the JS code, that's fine, though it might be worthwhile leaving it in place for all users until they click a 'start' button or something.

The splash screen page will also give you a starting point for somewhere to place your ads.

Comment: My page has keyword and description meta tags, and it shows up in Google just fine. This answer doesn't really address my question in any way...

Comment: @Codemonkey - I think you will have a hard time getting an answer you want - JanDvorak has given you the only real option available to you. If Google wants to see DOM elements and text, but you only provide that to JS-enabled user agents, you won't be able to pass it's restrictions.

Comment: @DanJ: Sure, but Google is not the only advertisement company in the world.

Comment: They're not the only search engine in the world either. But the same issues will likely apply to all the big players.